# Jquery UI autocomplete in jqGrid search not sending the data

Tags: jqgrid

Here's a weird problem I'm facing.
I want to attach a jqueryui autocomplete to a search field in jqgrid.

I have this for the column:

```
{
    name: 'client',
    index: 'client_name',
    width: 40,
    sortable: true,
    searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: "{{ URL::action('ClientsController@ajax') }}",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(elem).val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It all works fine, it adds me the value in the field but when I press the "Find" button, the actual field value is empty. If I don't select anything from the autocomplete and I just type it, it works just fine.
If I attach a datepicker to a field, it works just fine after selection. It doesn't want to work with autocomplete.

Did anyone else have this problem before? Any tips?

I'm using jqgrid 4.5.4 and jqueryui 1.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested, I found a fix for this. Works about 99% of the cases.

Just add `$(elem).trigger('change');` in the select event for the autocomplete;

So full script would be

```
{
name: 'client',
index: 'client_name',
width: 40,
sortable: true,
searchoptions: {
    dataInit: function (elem) {
        $(elem).autocomplete({
            source: "{{ URL::action('ClientsController@ajax') }}",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $(elem).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}